# Restrict manually added dependencies (to local .m2) form getting updated from remote repositories

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I have this weird situation. I have an spring boot application and in that application there are some legacy jars were needed to run the application.  mvn does not allow to have a lib folder. So I added the jars to the local maven repository.

This worked well (Till there are no repositories declared in the pom file) till I wanted to add, spring-batch-admin.version 2.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT, to my project.

So, when I added this,

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots-local</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/</url>

        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

I get good amount of Missing artifact, and also when I tried to run mvn install in command line, i get,

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ccc.cccc-tool:webapp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ccj:CCjJDBC:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ccj:CCjJDBC:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact com.ccc:CCjJDBC:pom:1.0 from/to spring-snapshots-local (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/): Failed to transfer file: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/com/ccj/CCjJDBC/1.0/CCjJDBC-1.0.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I am not think of uploading these legacy jars to the maven central to get this to working. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Start using a repository manager and install those legacy jars into the repository and afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies not special handling needed anymore..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the local repository into your project. For example, your have a jar file

```
group: com.packagename
artifactId: somejarfile
version: 2.0.0b
```

Then add this code into your pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>localDependenciesRepo</id>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/localDependenciesRepo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then create a folder for this repository **src/main/resources/localDependenciesRepo**. Create a folder structure for the library: **com -> packagename -> somejarfile -> 2.0.0b**. "->" means new folder of course.
And put your jar file into this folder. 
Don't forget to copy/create pom.xml file for your jar file. As example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.packagename</groupId>
  <artifactId>somejarfile</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0b</version>
</project>
```

At least I use this solution and it works perfectly.